# Cómo encontrar una etiqueta en un iframe

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando una etiqueta de otra página que también pertenece al mismo dominio, pero no logro encontrarla ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
var s = document.getElementById("search");

var x = s.document.querySelector(".red-tag");

x.style.color = "green";
```

```html
<iframe id="search" src="www.pagina.com"></iframe>


<!-- EN LA OTRA PÁGINA SE ENCUENTRA -->

<div class="red-tag">
<span>Texto</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba quitar en la segunda línea de código la s en "s.document.querySelector(".red-tag")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `s` hace referencia solo a la etiqueta `<iframe>`, no a su contenido. Necesitas usar la propiedad [`.contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow):

```
let s = document.getElementById("search").contentWindow;
let x = s.document.querySelector(".red-tag");
x.style.color = "green";
```